# Copy directories if their subdirectories contain "connect.txt"

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, copy

I want to copy multiple directories from one location to another location only if any of the subdirectories of those contain `connect.txt` file in them.

Example:

```
ANIMAL\DOG\CONNECT.TXT
PLANET\EARTH\CONNECT.TXT
SYSTEM\USER\ADMIN.TXT
```

Then I ONLY want to copy `ANIMAL` & `PLANET` directories to `C:\DESKTOP`.

Comment: Please feel free to let us know how you get on.

Answer (score -1):

`move *\*\connect.txt C:\Desktop` 
This uses a regular expression which would work if you're really wanting to look only under the subdirectories of all directories at some location.

Comment: That is a wildcard, not a regular expression. Using multiple directory levels only possible in PowerShell which isn't on topic for this question.